# When does it make sense to transmigrate/reincarnate story characters?

Tags: disgaea

I'm still fairly early on in *Disgaea*. I've just started Map 4, and Laharl is only level 18 or so.

I see that I have the option to Transmigrate him. As I understand it, transmigration makes a lot of sense for my newly-created characters, as I effectively upgrade what class they are (like Cleric to Priest or Bishop). However, for characters like Laharl and Etna, they can't upgrade their class or change class, so the only benefit seems to be that they may get some more ability points, depending on how much mana I spend.

I'm left with some questions about when it's worth it do this. Are the ability bonuses cumulative, such that if I transmigrate him 10 times, I'll get 10 times worth of stat bonsues? Or will my 2nd transmigration wipe out the ability bonuses of the first?

- If they do stack, does it ever make sense to transmigrate as a Genius, since it costs a heck of a lot more mana (8000) to get 10 points, whereas I could transmigrate 10 times for +1 ability points (only costs 10 mana each time!)?
- If it doesn't stack, will I ever need to transmigrate again once I've transmigrated at the Genius level?
- What's the "Inheritance Bonus" percentage, and how does this affect things?

Comment: The first five transmigrations for Story characters also improves their aptitudes for all stats by 5% each time

Comment: @Rarity So would it be a positive effect or detrimental to to crank out 5 quick transmigrations at 10 mana each? +25% seems nice!

Comment: @Stetno You'll lose your skill levels and weapon levels due to the inheritance rate, especially if you can't afford the best level of inheritance. +25% is pretty nice though. This depends how easily you can level new characters though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Story Characters are great to migrate the first 5 times because you get a 5% aptitude bonus for all stats the first 5 times; aptitude % means you gain that much of your equipment's stats as a %. So after 5 transmigrations you get 25% more out of all equipment for that character!

However, transmigrating shouldn't be done lightly unless you can very easily level your characters. You'll have to level your characters over again and gain enough mana for them to transmigrate again.

The main reason for transmigrating to Genius is because of the **Inheritance Rate**. Inheritance rate is how much of your Skill and Weapon experience you lose when you transmigrate. If you have 1000 Ax Skill and transmigrate with 50% inheritance rate, you now have 500 Ax Skill. Since there is no easy way to grind Weapon Level or Skill Level, losing skill level really hurts. Doing it early on can be good if you're sure you can get the mana/levels back in reasonable time.

If you can't easily get enough mana to migrate your character as a Genius, **don't transmigrate yet**. Disgaea is not about grinding, it's about grinding *intelligently*. You're too early in the game to worry about this from what I can tell.

Ability points don't stack in the way you describe; you always get 10 for genius, and you get a set amount of points extra for that character based on their total level.

Comment: I'll just add a note to this answer... right around the time I decided to look at Transmigrating, I was at map 4-1, which coincidentally has geo-panels that give +100% experience. It made it a really great place to re-level my guys, particularly if you throw the 4 guys right by the start into each other to make one mega-monster. It was a little tough making sure the right guy got the killing blow sometimes, but it rockets guys up from level 1 to about level 16 after doing it 2 or 3 times, which is about what I was at before transmigration.

Comment: @Sterno is that the one with Succubi? Look for a map covered in Succubi that has invincibility panels, it's a perfect place for early leveling.

Comment: No, this one had Scarecrows. It's the first location listed [here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Disgaea:_Hour_of_Darkness/Levelling)

Comment: @Sterno ah. For reference, 9-1 should be a really good map, a bit aways yet though